# reading Xml file on android

Tags: java, android, xmlpullparser

I'm trying to read a Xml file with 120 items like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <books>
        <Book>
            <bookName >Libro 1</bookName>
            <bookSection>Unidad 1</bookSection>
            <memorization>[A long string of information]…</memorization>
        </Book>
        <Book>.....</Book>
 </books>
```

In my android app I want to put all this information in a `ArrayList<book>`

So in the void OnCreate I do this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
XmlResourceParser x = res.getXml(R.xml.textos);
        try {
            insertXML(x);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and InsertXML look like this.

```
private void insertXML(XmlPullParser x) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {        
        try {

            int eventType = x.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                Textos seleccion = new Textos();

                if ( eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG ) {
                    if (x.getAttributeValue(null, "Book") != null) {
                        seleccion.setBook(x.getAttributeValue(null, "bookName"));
                        seleccion.setSection(x.getAttributeValue(null, "bookSection"));
                        seleccion.setMemorization(x.getAttributeValue(null, "memorization"));
                    }

                }

                if ( eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG ) {
                    if (x.getName().equals("Book")) {
                        texto.add(seleccion);
                    }
                }

                eventType = x.next();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

That make a mistake because never go in `if (x.getAttributeValue(null, "Book") != null) {`

And when I used the debug mode tell me that `x.depth() = 0`

So, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Book` isn't an attribute - it's an element (a tag). You should use:

```
if (x.getName().equals("Book"))
```

to check whether you're on the `Book` element. However, that won't really help you much, as you're actually after the `bookName`, `bookSection` and `memorization` tags. I suspect you actually want (within the check for the `START_TAG` event):

```
if (x.getName().equals("bookName")) {
    seleccion.setBook(x.nextText());
} else if (x.getName().equals("bookSection")) {
    seleccion.setSection(x.nextText());
} else if (x.getName().equals("memorization")) {
    seleccion.setMemorization(x.nextText());
}
```

It's important to understand the difference between elements and attributes. For example, in:

```
<x y="z">Foo</x>
```

The *element* is `<x>`, `y` is an attribute with a value of `"z"`, and `Foo` is the text within the `x` element.

Comment: Thanks Jon that help me a little but my idea is to put all the information of the XML in a ArrayList<Textos>
Textos is a class with 3 string ( Book, Section, Memorization)

So now I dont know how to continue on it.

Some help?

Comment: @David_Garcia: Well I've helped you in terms of extracting information from the XML pull parser. If you're stuck on the rest, that sounds like a different question. Is there any reason for using a pull parser here anyway? It would be easier to use a DOM API, I suspect.

Comment: I was reading that right now and Im using DOM API that its much much better and fix all my problems

Thanks for help!